# restart libvirtd --listen error

Tags: migrate, libvirt, systemctl

libvirt version: 3.2.0

this is my config of libvirtd.conf.

```
vim /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
auth_tcp = "none"
```

If I do not use the above configuration, I shut down and restart libvirt without any problems. But because I want to live migrate, so I need to add the above parameters, After adding problems, and Cause the shutdown and restart failed

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service 

[root@localhost wl]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service 
# NB we don't use socket activation. When libvirtd starts it will
# spawn any virtual machines registered for autostart. We want this
# to occur on every boot, regardless of whether any client connects
# to a socket. Thus socket activation doesn't have any benefit

[Unit]
Description=Virtualization daemon
Requires=virtlogd.socket
Requires=virtlockd.socket
Before=libvirt-guests.service
After=network.target
After=dbus.service
After=iscsid.service
After=apparmor.service
After=local-fs.target
After=remote-fs.target
Documentation=man:libvirtd(8)
Documentation=http://libvirt.org

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/libvirtd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $LIBVIRTD_ARGS **-d -l**
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
# At least 1 FD per guest, often 2 (eg qemu monitor + qemu agent).
# eg if we want to support 4096 guests, we'll typically need 8192 FDs
# If changing this, also consider virtlogd.service & virtlockd.service
# limits which are also related to number of guests
LimitNOFILE=8192

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=virtlockd.socket
Also=virtlogd.socket
```

-d -l above the bold work, Also to support live migrate plus

firstly I use "systemctl start libvirtd" to start libvirt,

then systemctl stop libvirtd, but the libvirt don't' close

The problem is that I use the "systemctl restart libvirtd" command will be an error

Want to ask what is the problem? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The following parameters you have set:

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
auth_tcp = "none"
```

are **A MASSIVE SECURITY HOLE**. A connection to libvirtd is considered to give privileges equivalent to a root account. So by turning off all authentication, and using the TCP socket instead of TLS socket, you have opened up a remote root shell with no encryption or authentication.  This is on a par with running a telnet server and allowing root login with no password. **Simply never do this**.  Any docs telling you to do this for live migration and wrong - I've been trying to get all such docs taken offline for ages, but people keep posting this bogus advice again & again.

The following page describes how to setup certificates for TLS

https://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_certificates

If you really don't want to use TLS, then the best fallback is to tell libvirtd to use SSH tunnelling to connect to the remote host.

WRT to the unit file, you shouldn't need to modify that directly. Notice that it refers to a file `/etc/sysconfig/libvirtd`, just edit that cnofig file and set LIBVIRTD_ARGS variable there to include `--listen`.

You say you got an error running systemctl start, but don't say what the error was... It is pretty hard/impossible to provide guidance on what the problem is without knowing the real error you get. Try 'systemctl status libvirtd.service' to find the useful error message(s).